# I need help about "save as"

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

I need help
**macros**

```
Sub newbook()
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add 
Do 
    fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename 
Loop Until fName <> False 
NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=fName 'showing yellow
```

This code don't work on excel 2003 and 2007

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Run-time error '438'

Comment: Weird - I would assume that `Workbook.SaveAs` is valid in those Excel versions. Are you on Windows or Mac?

Comment: I have  windows to work

Comment: Try it with ```NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=fName & „xlsx“ ```

Comment: No, sorry, it is don't work

Answer (score 0):

It is no clear what you say:

First, is important to fix some points in your code:

```
Option Explicit '   It is a good practice to use it always. This force your code to
                '   "ask" for every var to be declare before use it

Sub newbook_1() ' Never use the same name for a var and a function/sub inside the same function/sub. That is why i change it

    'as I told you Option Explicit requieres a declaration of the var before
    'Here I use one line declaration. It is the same
    'if you use this:
    '   Dim NewBook As Workbook
    '   Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    'but just in one line
    Dim NewBook As Workbook: Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

    Dim fName 'When you declare a variable, IF you don't define a var type, the var always will be Variant
    'It is the same this:
    '   Dim fName As Variant
    Do
        fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename 'Ask for the name and directory...
    Loop Until fName <> False 'Validate if the user put a name...
                              'Notice: when a new workbook is create and save it will set "Book#" as a default name
                              'when the dialog is called. Where the # is the following consecutive number
    NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=fName, FileFormat:=51 'Here!
                                                   ' Save the file, with the name provide it for the user,
                                                   'whit the file format you want.
End Sub
```

This code works completely fine for me. Give it a try!

Comment: Name in the code's orginal 
Sub CreoteAndSave()

____is this all the code that's with the blacks ?
if Yes, it saves the new book as a file and need to open it using help
_______________if not, you can explain ____________   sorry for( ___) I don't know how to put spaces here

Comment: You can edit your question, and amplify the question, be more clear and I will help you.

Comment: ```sub CreoteAndSave() ' new name
Dim NewBook As Workbook: Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

    Dim fName 
  
    Do
        fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename 
    Loop Until fName <> False
                              
    NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=fName, FileFormat:=51 
                                                                                   
End Sub
```
It is full code ?
it does not save an excel file, but just a file and you need to open it using "open with" 
these are the problems